# Data dump of ZIP codes to Carrier Route IDs and the centroid (lat/long.) of the Carrier Route

Tags: data-request, geospatial, postal-code

I am trying to find an open database (or cheap commercial) that I can download; perhaps a CSV that would have all centroids of carrier routes for a ZIP code.
There are roughly fifteen Carrier Routes per postal ZIP Code, see the image for an example (though the example shows a carrier route polygon; I only need the centroid). In the image, for example the ZIP code 60625 has CXXX carrier routes.

[image]

I thought this mapping would be available at the Census Bureau site (because they have ZIP code boundaries) or USPS, but it is not...

There are about 600,000 carrier routes in the US, according to [this blog](https://www.everydoordirectmail.com/Postal-Carrier-Routes-Everything-You-Need-to-Know-blogpost353).

Comment: usps zip codes are proprietary. this was an extremely hard pill for me to swallow and actually helped further my resolve in the open data/open gov space.

Comment: i hear ya @albert! ..i am able to buy zipcodes from a 3rd party and census bureau(for boundaries)....can you look at this question...this person stated he used the USPS API to get carrier routes by zipcde... but i cannot find such an API...https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/192575/packing-polygons-without-intersection-and-empty-places

Comment: i found two places you can scrape for carrier routes, which isn't what you want, but maybe of use to you? You have two options if you are open to scraping the data.  
[everydoordirectmail.com](https://www.everydoordirectmail.com/Step1-Target.aspx), and [melissa.com/lookups/](https://www.melissa.com/lookups/mapcarts.asp?zip=99506).  
A cursory glance of the two, the latter is setup for scraping with a much clearer path.

Comment: Thanks..@albert/, was able to at least obtain the centroid of each carrier route(about 250,000 non-Po Box)... https://gist.github.com/boundaries-io/cf6db2b7c3a43404d45c3143b5e02c9e#file-carrerroute_60630-geojson

Comment: nice. can you share the code that made that? i want them for virginia.

Comment: I used "Voronoi" on exiting latitude/longitudes.  here is a blog I used to figure it out: https://longair.net/blog/2017/07/10/approximate-postcode-boundaries/

Answer (score 3):

I was able to complete this by generating internal boundaries for Carrier Route data using Voronoi. the endpoints to query for carrier routes exist on [boundaries-io.com](https://boundaries-io.com) 
here is a link to a blog where i figured it out...if this helps someone.

(I don't own this blog)
https://longair.net/blog/2017/07/10/approximate-postcode-boundaries

[image]

Final zipcode 60630 with carrier boundaries generated:

[image]

*disclaimer I work for boundaries-io.com*